# Finding out if the device is locked, from a Notification Widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I'd like to know if the device is locked when I'm loading my Notification/Today widget, so I can show the widget appropriately. (it's financial, and we don't want to show balances on a locked phone)

On devices with TouchID, I can just try to access the Keychain, and if I get

`errSecInteractionNotAllowed`

back, it's locked. All good. **This doesn't work on devices without touchID** (but with a PIN). I've found a few things, which recommend using

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] protectedDataAvailable]`

However I don't have `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in a widget.

Any ideas where and how to do this? I just need a yes/no: is the device locked.

Thanks

[UPDATE: here's the code I have]

Getting the filename:

```
+ (NSString *)lockedDeviceFilename {
    NSURL *directoryUrl = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:USER_DEFAULTS_GROUP_NAME];
   return [directoryUrl.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"security.dummy"];
}
```

Writing / creating the file (in the app, not the extension:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *documentPath = [FOOStorageGatekeeper lockedDeviceFilename];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:documentPath error:&error];

BOOL created = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentPath
                                                       contents:[@"super secret file contents. we only care about the permissions" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                     attributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionComplete}];
```

Reading:

```
 BOOL isReadable = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[FOOStorageGatekeeper lockedDeviceFilename]];

  NSLog(@"isReadable? %@", isReadable ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

It's always able to read the file, even on a TouchID device with the screen locked. If I look at the attributes, it shows the NSFileProtectionKey is set to NSFileProtectionComplete... but I can STILL READ IT :(

Update: found it. Marking Ian's answer as correct

Comment: Checking if a file exists is not the same as verifying that it's readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a file with `NSFileProtectionComplete` while your app is running and then attempt to access it from your extension. If you can't access it, the screen is locked.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:someFilePath
                                        contents:[@"Lock screen test." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                      attributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionComplete}];
```

**EDIT**: Final steps included to complete solution and consolidate answers. (Remaining work provided by Nic Wise.)

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[FOOStorageGatekeeper lockedDeviceUrl] options: NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

if (error != nil && error.code == 257) {
    NSLog(@"**** the keychain appears to be locked, using the file method");
    return YES;
}
```

The other method, using `errSecInteractionNotAllowed` also works, but only for TouchID devices.

I found the answer (indirectly) [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1088804#1088804) (rego with the iOS dev program most likely needed)

Comment: Thanks Ian - I tried that, but I was creating it from the Extension. I'll try again from the app. Thanks

Comment: Marking Ian's answer as correct, as he was mostly there - see my own reply for how to read it back (you need both, obv)

Comment: I updated the answer to include your work just so it's all in one place.

Comment: This is all great, but only works when the user has a passcode

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after 3-4 days of looking, found the answer. It was more in how I was reading the result back. Ian is right: I need to create the file using createFileAtPath, but then read it back using

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[FOOStorageGatekeeper lockedDeviceUrl] options: NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

if (error != nil && error.code == 257) {
    NSLog(@"**** the keychain appears to be locked, using the file method");
    return YES;
}
```

The other method, using `errSecInteractionNotAllowed` also works, but only for TouchID devices.

I found the answer (indirectly) [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1088804#1088804) (rego with the iOS dev program most likely needed)

Answer (score 1):

I tried that and my file was always readable (in lock screen or not).

I found this document :
https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

It appeared that the files are locked 10 seconds after the device is locked.

Knowing that, you can create the files from the extensions, and it seems to work.