# iOS Today Widget Extension - detect if screen is locked

Tags: ios, lockscreen, today-extension

I have a today extension that displays a timer.  I want to pause the timer when the screen is locked, but can't figure out how to detect if the screen is locked.

I tried doing this but the file is always readable even when the screen is locked:
[Finding out if the device is locked, from a Notification Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933666/finding-out-if-the-device-is-locked-from-a-notification-widget)

I was able to do this in my app using this but am unable to implement it in a widget:
[How can I detect screen lock/unlock events on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

The way Today Extensions work, they will not be executing when Notification Center is closed. The method `viewDidDisappear` will be called when the Today Extension is no longer visible and you can stop your timer there.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I ended up doing....

1. Moved the lock screen detection to the container app
2. Used notify_get_state (see
   [Is there a way to check if the iOS device is locked/unlocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked/14271472#14271472))
3. Ran a background task in the app

Comment: and the screen detection works if the app is in background? Which capabilities have you enabeld?