# iOS Today Widget in Lockscreen

Tags: ios, widget

I'm trying to prevent my widget to be shown on the lockscreen since it shows sensitive information. I know I can disable them all in Settings but this is not ideal. I'd like to know if there is another way to hide my widget only on the lockscreen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933666/finding-out-if-the-device-is-locked-from-a-notification-widget

Comment: That could be a way to check if the device is locked. However, due to the cached content we will still be able to see it on the lockscreen. Is there any way to prevent this to happen?